# exit code 11 in biopython

Tags: python, exit-code, biopython

can someone help me make sense of this error message? Its from an IPython cell in Beaker Notebook, running T-cofee in command line through biopython.

```
Non-zero return code 11 from 't_coffee -output clustalw -infile /Applications/Beaker.app/Contents/Resources/dist/src/main/web/uniprot-ornithine+transcarbamylase-2.fasta -outfile /Applications/Beaker.app/Contents/Resources/dist/src/main/web/aligned.aln', message 'PROGRAM: T-COFFEE Version_11.00.8cbe486 (2014-08-12 21:55:14 - Revision 8cbe486 - Build 470)'
Non-zero return code 11 from 't_coffee -output clustalw -infile /Applications/Beaker.app/Contents/Resources/dist/src/main/web/uniprot-ornithine+transcarbamylase-2.fasta -outfile /Applications/Beaker.app/Contents/Resources/dist/src/main/web/aligned.aln', message 'PROGRAM: T-COFFEE Version_11.00.8cbe486 (2014-08-12 21:55:14 - Revision 8cbe486 - Build 470)'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ApplicationError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-5970d9b8d2e2> in <module>()
     97 tcoffee_cline = TCoffeeCommandline(infile="/Applications/Beaker.app/Contents/Resources/dist/src/main/web/%s"%(fName2), output="clustalw", outfile="/Applications/Beaker.app/Contents/Resources/dist/src/main/web/aligned.aln")
     98 #executes command line wrapper
---> 99 tcoffee_cline()
    100 #read in the alignment file
    101 alignment = AlignIO.read(open("/Applications/Beaker.app/Contents/Resources/dist/src/main/web/aligned.aln"), "clustal")

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Bio/Application/__init__.pyc in __call__(self, stdin, stdout, stderr, cwd, env)
    513         if return_code:
    514             raise ApplicationError(return_code, str(self),
--> 515                                    stdout_str, stderr_str)
    516         return stdout_str, stderr_str
    517 

ApplicationError: Non-zero return code 11 from 't_coffee -output clustalw -infile /Applications/Beaker.app/Contents/Resources/dist/src/main/web/uniprot-ornithine+transcarbamylase-2.fasta -outfile /Applications/Beaker.app/Contents/Resources/dist/src/main/web/aligned.aln', message 'PROGRAM: T-COFFEE Version_11.00.8cbe486 (2014-08-12 21:55:14 - Revision 8cbe486 - Build 470)'
```

Happy to answer any questions if it will help.
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the reformatting. New here, couldn't figure out how to format it once the help bar disappeared...

Comment: I'm going to guess here:  It looks as if t_coffee can't interpret the command that's been produced and is instead returning its name (message 'PROGRAM: T-COFFEE Version_11.00.8cbe486 (2014-08-12 21:55:14 - Revision 8cbe486 - Build 470)) and that is the source of the "11".  I will also guess that having a "+" in your in file may be confusing t_coffee.  Does the command work when you remove that?

Comment: I tried that and am now getting a new error code:   Non-zero return code 127 from 't_coffee -output clustalw -infile /Applications/Beaker.app/Contents/Resources/dist/src/main/web/temp.fasta -outfile /Applications/Beaker.app/Contents/Resources/dist/src/main/web/temp.al', message '/bin/sh: t_coffee: command not found'

Comment: That's suggesting you don't have t_coffee independently installed. Your earlier error message suggested that you do, though.  What happens if you run the command (t_coffee -output clustalw -infile /Applications/Beaker.app/Contents/Resources/dist/src/main/web/temp.fasta -outfile /Applications/Beaker.app/Contents/Resources/dist/src/main/web/temp.al) directly from the command line?

Comment: Seems to run properly when I run that line directly in terminal. Does that suggest that its a problem within Biopython, rather than TCoffee?

Comment: It just started working fine without my changing anything...